# Webrequest.GetResponse() works on development machine, not on client machines

Tags: c#, winforms, webrequest

I tried using WebRequest.GetResponse() on my developement machine(XP) and it works properly and I can read the response stream from the URL, but the compiled code fails on two client machines(Windows 7) when the URL is identical. The WebException.Status is "The network request is not supported." Why would that occur whan trying to access the same URL? The WebException is fired by the GetResponse method. In the catch clause, the response object and the WebException.Response objects are both null. What can I do to further diagnose the problem?

```
WebRequest request = null;
HttpWebResponse response = null;
Stream dataStream = null;
StreamReader reader = null;
String responseFromServer = string.Empty;
string http = string.Empty;
int timeOut = 30000;
string errorMsg = string.Empty;
http = this.URLstring;
bool error = false;

try
{
    request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(http);
    request.Timeout = timeOut;
    response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (System.Net.WebException wex)
{
    error = true;
    errorMsg = wex.Message + " " + wex.Status.ToString();

    if (wex.Response != null)
    {
        WebHeaderCollection hdrs = wex.Response.Headers;

        for (int i = 0; i < hdrs.Count; i++)
            errorMsg += Environment.NewLine + hdrs.Keys[i] + ", " + hdrs[i];
    }
}

// Code to read the response stream goes here. it works on development machine.
```

Comment: Please indent your code - it's so much easier to read :)

Comment: Using using keyword is good idea too)

Comment: Posting the (full) Errormessage text might help.

Comment: @Shrike where do  you see HttpStatus used?

Comment: Put a "Works on my machine" picture somewhere on in your application :p JK!

Answer (score 2):

It could be a privileges matter. To test that, run the App under Win7 'As Administrator'